# Show items in Listbox automatically when Main Form is reloaded

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm just thinking if it is possible to view the items in listbox automatically when main form is reloaded.

```
FrmMain frm = new FrmMain();
frm.ShowDialog();
```

And when the Main Form show up, the items in listbox automatically show without any clicks or keydown events. Is this possible??

```
    private void BtnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ACICTest.FindbyACICNo(textBox1.Text).Count() == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No record found in the database!","ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            listBox1.DataSource = ACICTest.FindbyACICNo(textBox1.Text).ToList();
            listBox1.DisplayMember = "ACICNo";
            listBox1.ValueMember = "ACICId";
            listBox1.Focus();
        }
        dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
```

The code above is for the search button.

```
     private void BtnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int breaker = 0;
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure want to update the data?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Prior Year"].Value) > 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Accept 1 or 0 only. [Prior Year = 1] [Non-Prior = 0]", "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    breaker += 1;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    ACICComplete.UpdateData(new ACICCombinedDetails
                    {
                        GFCheckID = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ID"].Value),
                        PYear = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Prior Year"].Value)
                    });
                }
            }
            if (breaker >= 1)
            {
                //Empty Code
            }
            else
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Data successfully updated!", "Successful", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    BtnAdd.Enabled = false;
                    BtnSave.Enabled = false;
                    BtnCancel.Enabled = false;
                    BtnUpdate.Enabled = false;
                    listBox1.Enabled = true;
                    BtnTrustAdd.Enabled = false;
                    BtnTrustRemove.Enabled = false;
                    BtnEdit.Enabled = false;
                    dataGridView1.Columns["Prior Year"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
                    FrmMain.ActiveForm.Dispose();
                    FrmMain frm = new FrmMain();
                    frm.ShowDialog();
                  //In this portion the Main form shows up but I want listbox also show the items
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is for the update button

Comment: How you populate the listbox? Make it as a method and call in form_Load

Comment: I populate it using a button named Search item. But in First Run listbox should be empty first and then if I press the button update it will reload the mainform and show the items in the listbox.

Comment: ok then include that code in the question

Comment: Already added the code,.

Comment: Let me confirm, `BtnSearch_Click` and `BtnUpdate_Click` are in the same form `FrmMain ` ? you are going to open the current form again as a dialog or else

Comment: Yes, they are on the same form and yes I want to open the current form again as Dialog when I click on update. The Mainform has the Search Button, Update Button, Listbox and Datagridview. When the MainForm loaded again the items in listbox items must show. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution for you: Define a method like the following for populating the listboxes:

```
public void PopulateListboxes()
    {
        listBox1.DataSource = ACICTest.FindbyACICNo(textBox1.Text).ToList();
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "ACICNo";
        listBox1.ValueMember = "ACICId";
        listBox1.Focus();
    }
```

Now call the method in the button click; for load them;

```
 private void BtnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //condition if
        else
        {
           PopulateListboxes();
        }
       //rest of code
    }
```

For loading them in page load for `frm.ShowDialog();` use the following snippet:

```
  FrmMain.ActiveForm.Dispose();
  FrmMain frm = new FrmMain();
  frm.PopulateListboxes(); // this will populate the control
  frm.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Waaaaaaaaaaaaa! thank you so much Sir! You're great! You solved my problem! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should save the items of the list box in an xml file (to always keep your data even if you close your window) and reload it when you reload your window or any other events.